# Vbs - File Cont \ File Delete

Tags: vbscript

I am creating a guy script read files in a folder, (`Scripting.FileSystemObject`), but I would like to relate a indice inpubox type int to determine which file in the folder I'll write on the screen.

Ex: `indice = inputbox ""` ← 4 grab the indice file in the folder 4 and esquever your name on the screen.
  I wonder if this is possible because already tried in many ways and even by matrix, but without result.

This and my code. I do not know but where to go!

```
Dim sFO, NovaPasta, Folder,File, Indice          
Dim inpast(4)

'Setup

Set sFO =  CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = sFo.GetFolder("C:\Users\502526523\Documents\Control")
NovaPasta = "Control"

'Development

If Not sFO.FolderExists (NovaPasta) = True Then
  sFO.CreateFolder (NovaPasta)
  Wscript.Sleep 900 
  WScript.Echo "Pasta Criada"
Else
  WScript.Echo "Pasta Existente "
End If

' Line Verificas a quantidade de inpastas dentro da pasta, se > 5
' deleta os exedentes com data mais antiga

For Each file In folder.Files
  If Folder.Files.Count > 5 And (DateDiff("d", file.DateLastModified, Now) > 7) Then
    WScript.Echo  (file.Name & vbLf)
    WScript.Echo ("Total files :" & Folder.Files.Count)
    File.Delete
  End If
Next

For Each file In folder.Files
  inpast(0) = (file.Name)
  inpast(1) = (file.Name)
  inpast(2) = (file.Name)
  inpast(3) = (file.Name)
  inpast(4) = (file.Name)

  Indice = Inputbox ("Digite o valor do Indice de 0...30")

  Select Case Indice
    Case 0
      WScript.Echo inpast(0)
    Case 1
      WScript.Echo inpast(1)
    Case 2
      WScript.Echo inpast(2)
    Case 3
      WScript.Echo inpast(3)
    Case 4
      WScript.Echo inpast(4)
  End Select
Next
```

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible.

Comment: Google translator ------,                                                                            I need to get the name in the folder however intuitively, if I type a number in imputbox this has to search the file corresponding to the number of imputbox, ie co-relation.

inputbox = 7 --------
msgbox = file name (7) inside the folder
I tried to use an array with a case but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure if I understand your question correctly. You mean you have a list of filenames and you want to display the filename corresponding to the number the user entered via an `InputBox`? If that's what you want you should change your second `For Each` loop like this:

```
i = 0
For Each file In folder.Files
  inpast(i) = file.Name
  i = i + 1
Next

Indice = InputBox("Digite o valor do Indice de 0...30")
WScript.Echo inpast(CInt(Indice))
```

Note, however, that the condition in your first `For Each` loop does not guarantee you'll only ever have 5 files left after the loop. If for some reason the folder contains more than 5 files that were modified within the past 7 days the second loop would fail with a "subscript out of range" error.

There are several ways you could handle this:

- [Dynamically resize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17664578/1630171) the `inpast` array so it can hold more than 5 items.
- Sort the files in the folder by last modification date (e.g. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16289700/1630171)) and delete everything except the 5 most recent files.
- Cut off the second `For Each` loop after the 5<sup>th</sup> iteration (`Exit For`).

Note also, that you should sanitize your input. (What happens when users enter text, an invalid number, or press "Cancel"?)

Comment: Good Morning Dear!
Sorry for the delay in responding ....
I appreciate the help, now the first thing to fix and stop responding to you guys, because if not I would not again !!!

Ansgar Wiechers - His solution was just what I needed, I had emcontrado pareceda one solution, but I could not format the question of Ciint conversion because I was trying to convert the file.count and did not work, but with his cod. It worked perfectly on your perguna part delete, it's working, I tested a folder with 54 old and new files and it worked well.
I am grateful for the great help ...

Answer (score 0):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dirname = InputBox("Enter Dir name")
'Searchterm = Inputbox("Enter search term")
ProcessFolder DirName

Sub ProcessFolder(FolderPath)
'    On Error Resume Next
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    msgbox fls.count
    Msgbox fls.item("computerlist.txt") 
End Sub
```

To do the 7th

```
    Set Fls = fldr.files

    For Each thing in Fls
        Count = Count + 1
        If count = 7 then msgbox Thing.Name & " " & Thing.DateLastModified 
    Next
```

Comment: Good Morning Dear!
Sorry for the delay in responding ....
I appreciate the help, now the first thing to fix and stop responding to you guys, because if not I would not again !!!

Noodles - Your solution I can not completely test she is giving problem on line 9 required object 'folios' cod: 800ª01A8 will also test more and send one soon answer.

Comment: Enter a full directory name like `c:\windows` or change `Sub ProcessFolder(FolderPath)` to `Sub ProcessFolder("c:\windows")`

Comment: Typing the name of the directory C: \ Users \ Simatic \ Desktop \ Control fails line 9
Object required: 'fls' Cod: 800A01A8

  Replacing Sub ProcessFolder ( "C: \ Users \ Simatic \ Desktop \ Control")
Displays Error Line 6 expected identifier Cod: 800A03F2

Comment: Why all the spaces in the file path.